# how much does 1 second of error impact sidereal tracking?

Tags: observational-astronomy

Usually observatories have time servers on site for reasonable time keeping.

If I have 1 second of time error, how will this impact sidereal tracking? By how much?

Comment: It would only be an issue on initial alignment (by 15 arcseconds).  After the alignment is corrected, the mount will track at the sidereal rate.  Mechanical and atmospheric effects are usually more of a factor.

Answer (score 3):

Earth rotates approximately 15" per second, 15' per minute, 15 degrees per hour.